# Delete directories dated Jan, 2010 on Linux

Tags: sed

I want to use the following command to delete directories dated Jan 2010 only

```
ls -lh | awk '{print $6 " " $9}' | sed -n '/Jan/p' | awk '{print $2}' >>/tmp/file_list
```

The above command will list all directories dated Jan, but I have in my list Jan 2010 and Jan 2011.

Can anyone can help me with the SED command to list only the directories date Jan, 2010?

Comment: find is specifically created to solve problems like that. Take the time to master it, it make problems like this seam trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep instead of awk/sed, maybe something like this?

```
ls -lh | grep -o 'Jan [ 1-2][0-9]  2010 .*$' | awk '{print $4}' >> /tmp/file_list
```

The problem with what you have is the first awk is not including the years, so 2011 (or 2009, 2008, etc) all show up in the list that gets sent to sed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i got the list of directories but is there a way to print date in the output file?

Comment: If you want the date and the file, you can get rid of the last awk (which prints the file only). Without the last awk, you will get: "Jan" then the date, then "2010" then the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Never attempt to parse the output of `ls` for anything other than display purposes --- it is a [bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Though it uses find and xargs instead of sed, maybe something like this would work.  Note that it is untested.

```
jan01="$(date -d '20100101 00:00' +%s)"
feb01="$(date -d '20100201 00:00' +%s)"

today="$(date -d '23:59:59' +%s)"

daysecs="$((24*60*60))" # 86400 

dayssincefeb01="$(((today - feb01) / daysecs ))"
dayssincejan01="$(((today - jan01 + 1) / daysecs ))"

find /path -type d -mtime +"$dayssincefeb01" -mtime -"$dayssincejan01" \
-print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

The find command at the end finds directories that are older than 01 Feb 2010 but younger than 01 Jan 2010 and pipes them safely to xargs using the `'\0'` null character.

Comment: ./rm_dir_test.sh: line 1: 24*60*60: command not found
./rm_dir_test.sh: line 8: ): syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")")
./rm_dir_test.sh: line 9: ): syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")")
find: invalid argument `+' to `-mtime'

Comment: @AlBouazizi Sorry I had a typo on that line (missing a parenthesis).  Should be fixed now.

Comment: thank you for your effort..  i want to test the output with xargs -0 ls -l >>output.file is it doable?

Comment: You can just replace the `rm -r` with `ls -l`.